# Confusing attributes in angularjs directive's link function

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm writing an angular.js directive, which would conditionally hide the element.
So it would look like this:

```
link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
      ...
      elem.hide()
}
```

I found a lot of examples that were doing exactly that, but somehow my elem attribute is an array not an element, so it does not have a hide() method.
What am I missing?

Thanks!

Comment: Sorry it's not an array, and looks like the hide/show methods were removed from this object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most people are loading jQuery before they load angular, which extends its jqLite to the full jQuery.

The `hide` method doesn't seem to be part of jqLite API (https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element), hence such method is not exposed.

That doesn't mean you need jQuery, but that it is not the correct way to handle your problem. There are already the `ng-show` and `ng-if` directives to conditionnaly hide an element based on the controller, couldn't you use them?

In your html, add `<div ng-show="isDisplayed">,` and in your linking function `scope.isDisplayed = false`

Comment: Oh, you are right, thanks :) I don't think that the ng-show is good to me here, I'm creating a directive, that flashes a message, when it's content changes, and then hides itself automatically after a time interval. So I think I need the custom directive here. But now I see that I have the css method withouth jquery, so I can use this: element.css("display","none")